# How to color code rows conditionally in VB and SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

I am developing an ASPX file to return all records from a SQL table.  I can successfully get all of the numbers to show, but now I want certain rows to have their background colors changed if they meet certain criteria.  So I want to compare 2 of my columns to some value, and if it exceeds this value then it should change color of that row.  How can I fix below code?  Main problem is I don't know how to specify a column of data to compare.  No errors on this, but none of my rows have color changes either.

ASPX excerpt:

```
        Sub PrintMessageGrid_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim Six_In_A_Row As Integer = _
     Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, _
     "Six_In_A_Row"))
            If Six_In_A_Row = "1" Then
                ' color the background of the row yellow
                e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

And my HTML:

```
            <ASP:GridView id="dgTable" runat="server" AUTOGENERATECOLUMNS="true" ShowHeader="true" OnItemDataBound="PrintMessageGrid_RowDataBound">
                <HEADERSTYLE BackColor = "#336699" ForeColor = "#ffffff" Font-Bold = "true" />
            </ASP:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is how you access the value in the cells... maybe you can access cell value by using the GridViewRowEventArgs like this :

```
e.Row.Cells(1).Text
```

Maybe your code works too... you have only to change the condition! 
You are comparing an integer with a string... so your code must be changed in this code :

```
If Six_In_A_Row = 1 Then .....
```

Comment: If e.Row.Cells("Six_In_A_Row").Text = "1" Then
   ' color the background of the row yellow
   e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
End If

Answer (score 0):

.Tostring() is missing in DataBinder could be an issue.

And

In `If Six_In_A_Row = "1" Then`, you are comparing int with string. Do `Six_In_A_Row.ToString() = "1" then`

Use this example : http://www.dotnetwatch.com/change-the-specific-Row--Col389_AR.aspx

```
e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255,234,255); // Full row color
e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow; // Column color
```